# What does this "Langue et Littérature" textbook exercise want from me?

Tags: pronoms, verbes, conjugaison

I acquired an old Brigham Young textbook via garage sale, [*Langue et Littérature* by Thomas H. Brown](https://www.worldcat.org/title/langue-et-litterature-a-second-course-in-french-listening-speaking-reading-and-writing/oclc/11848998). It does not have many instructions, and I do not have the accompanying answer key, leaving me confused about the intent for some of these early exercises:

> **Structure: Révision du présent et de l'impératif (verbes comme parler, finir, attendre, et partir), du futur, de l'imparfait, et du conditionnel des verbes réguliers.**
> Dans les phrases suivantes, substituez les mots suggérés.

```
1. Habitez-vous ici?  
   ____________ à Genève?  
   ______ il ____________________?  
   ______ elles _________________?  
   ____________ en Allemagne?
   ______ vous __________________?
2. Tu ne finis jamais à l'heure.
   Vous _______________________.
   Je _________________________.
   _________________ avant six heures et demie.
   Nous ______________________________________.
   __________________ à temps.
   Ils _______________________.
   Elle ______________________.
```

I take it the length of the blanks (the proportions of which I have matched here) is some indication of what should be filled in, and that I should be creating variations of the first (complete) line, but it also implies that I should be making variations of successive lines that *I* create along the way, no?

But some don't have enough information to know what should be changed, and some have blanks that feel like it can be filled in with whatever my preference is. This is my best attempt:

1. Habitez-vous ici?
   **Habites-tu** à Genève? **(Was anything supposed to change?)**
   **Habite-** il **à Genève**? **(Why is the blank so long here?)**
   **Habitent-** elles **ici**? **(Maybe I should go back to the top example?)**
   **Habitez-vous** en Allemagne?  **(I don't think anything changes here)**
   **?** vous **?** ?  **(So, so lost by now)**
2. Tu ne finis jamais à l'heure.
   Vous **ne finissez jamais à l'heure**.
   Je **ne finis jamais à l'heure**.
   **Tu ne finis jamais** avant six heures et demie. **(No change necessary?)**
   Nous **ne finissons jamais avant six heures et demie**.
   **Tu ne finis jamais** à temps.
   Ils **ne finissent jamais à temps**.
   Elle **ne finit jamais à temps**.

Are some of these really supposed to be that easy, just copying the pronoun and verb as-is? Or is there something else more complicated going on here?

Comment: This might be off topic for asking more than one question at once, but you could frame it around the directions.  The directions are asking for more than just the present tense. What was covered in the lesson that lead to this review exercise?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: *Why is the blank so long here?* : Because what you wrote is slightly incomplete...